# Connecting PHP to Microsoft Windows 2012 R2 Server with MS SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, connection

I need a connection to my virtual machine. The machine is running on Windows 2012 R2 Standard. The installation is clean, and the firewall is already set to off. Now is the problem that I can't connect with my password. The server name is APP01 and the username is @Welkom1. This is my PHP code running on XAMPP.

```
$server = "APP01\SQLEXPRESS";$options = array(  "UID" => "APP01\Administrator",  "PWD" => "@Welkom1",  "Database" => "hetboekje");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);
if ($conn === false) die("<pre>".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
echo "Successfully connected!";sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

I get this error when I run this code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28000
            [SQLSTATE] => 28000
            [1] => 18456
            [code] => 18456
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'APP01\Administrator'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'APP01\Administrator'.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28000
            [SQLSTATE] => 28000
            [1] => 18456
            [code] => 18456
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'APP01\Administrator'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'APP01\Administrator'.
        )

)
```

I don't understand why this code not connect?
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Maybe google "sql server code 18456" ...

Comment: In SQL Server Mgmt. Studio, do you see that user in the Object Explorer, under > _Database_ > Security > Users? look at this snapshot for a hint: http://imgur.com/a/uS0dS

Comment: Sql logins was set to off. My stupid fault...